# Camel: split().tokenize("\r").streaming() does not work as expected

Tags: streaming, apache-camel

I'm going to process huge csv file with camel (over 3M records).
This works:

```
from("file:target/classes/data/")                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            .split().tokenize("\r").streaming()
```

This does not:

```
from("file:target/classes/data/")                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            .split().tokenize("\r").streaming()
```

Throws: `Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1`

Since `convertBodyTo(String.class)` is a huge waste of RAM, I'd avoid that.

What is the reason?

Comment: Maybe you need to set a charset in the file endpoint so the tokenizer can leverage that - http://camel.apache.org/file2

Comment: neither works: charset=UTF-8, charset=UTF8

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It was WINDOWS-1251 encoding. Now works. Thank you @ClausIbsen

Comment: Did u use System.getProperty("line.separator") instead of "\r"?

Comment: @Neron No I didn't, since same file won't dynamically change it separator on other OS :)

Comment: As you know, camel file component reads the file as metadata but when you say converBodyTo, it focuses on content and gives it to you(it is reasonable actually because a route should be atomic in itself. This approach does not look a file like lines . It looks a file as a whole item). So there is not a less memory consuming way to read it. Maybe you can split the huge file into smaller ones and use first usage.

Comment: The whole point was to get rid of `.convertBodyTo` to reduce memory consumption.

Comment: It does not seem possible for camel. So instead of removing convertbodyto, just try to split big files into smaller ones and convertbodyto will not consume as much memory as reading huge file

Comment: ```'from("file:target/classes/data?charset=WINDOWS-1251").split().tokenize("\r").streaming()``` this works like a charm for me

Comment: how about changing the order ? stream first and tokenize and aggregate as per \r later ?

Comment: @gap_j thanks, but ClausIbsen helped to solve.

Answer (score 0):

from("file:target/classes/data/")
            .unmarshal().string("UTF-8")
            .split().tokenize("\r").streaming()

This works for me.